# Database failed to open - Login failed for User

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm currently writing code to save information to a database.
I think I'm at now approaching the last hurdle for getting it to work.

My issue is that when I click save I get a message box saying, Cannot open Database [Database file path] requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for 'User-PC\User'.

However I didn't create any login details for the database as in the future I want anyone who uses the program to be able to log information into it.

I'm not quite sure where to look to solve the issue, but I am currently downloading SSMS to see if I can fix it there?

Any help would be great, thanks!

My code is,

string constring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=c: \users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\LossApplication\LossApplication\LossDB.mdf;Integrated Security=Yes; Trusted_Connection=True; ";

string query = " insert into LossDB.LossTable (lossid,Equipment, Event, responsinility, start) values(@lossid, @equipment, @Cause, @reason, @start) ;";

```
            SqlConnection conLossDB = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand cmdLossDB = new SqlCommand(query, conLossDB);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lossid", textBox1.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Equipment", comboBox1.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cause", comboBox2.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", comboBox3.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", dateTimePicker1.Text);
            //Defines which boxes to read in order to input the text from the defined boxes into the corresponding columns

            SqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conLossDB.Open();
                myReader = cmdLossDB.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("Loss Entry Saved");
                //Opens the database and carries out the defined command outlined in the code above

                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: try changing to  `Integrated Security = True`. or `Integrated Security = SSPI`.

Comment: I've tried both and get the same error box both times...

Comment: What are the permissions for the DB?  What logins exist on the server and what level of access do those logins have to your database?   If you want to allow "Everyone" to write to your database via your application, you may want to consider setting up a SQL account that your application will use to authenticate, then store the current user's info in the db itself (as sort of an audit trail) rather than use it to authenticate to the db directly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Integrated Security` means Windows Authentication mode of the sql server, there must be a valid Windows user that has access to the database. If you want to use this mode and give access to all user on the computer, you can configure Windows `Users` group (to which all users typically belongs to) to have access to your database (see Security->Logins in your database configuration).

Another approach is to create a SQL user and user SQL Server Authentication mode. Then you use this user login and password to get access to the database regardless of Windows user. In this case your connection string will looks like

```
(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=<path>\LossDB.mdf;User ID=<UserLogin>;Password=<***>;Trusted_Connection=True;
```